# How to update database using listview in vb.net

Tags: database, vb.net, listview

I am using a Listview to update database. It works perfect for the first row in listview. How can I update my database if there is more then one row in listview?

I have 6 columns in listview.

Listview Property changed to:

```
Hideselection = false
Multiselect = false
Fullrowselect = true
```

My Code:

```
For y = 0 To ListView1.Items.Count - 1
If (objcon.con.State = ConnectionState.Closed) Then objcon.con.Open()
cmd1 = New OleDbCommand("UPDATE Customers SET " & _
"fup = #" & ListView1.Items(0).SubItems(5).Text & "#" & _
"WHERE policy_no = '" & ListView1.Items(0).SubItems(1).Text & "'", objcon.con)
cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery()
objcon.con.Close()
Next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're close, you have your loop counter 'y', but you're not using it to access the elements in the listbox correctly:

Try this instead (I've typed this without an IDE so there may be typos...)

```
For y = 0 To ListView1.Items.Count - 1
    If (objcon.con.State = ConnectionState.Closed) Then 
        objcon.con.Open()
        cmd1 = New OleDbCommand("UPDATE Customers SET " & _
                                "fup = #" & ListView1.Items(y).SubItems(5).Text & "#" & _
                                "WHERE policy_no = '" & ListView1.Items(y).SubItems(1).Text & "'", objcon.con)
         cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery()
        objcon.con.Close()
    End If
Next
```

Comment: @ Derek: Thanks, sorry for being late to response.